# Классификация текстов

Tags: python

Как произвести более узкую классификацию текстов( политических новостей) по словарю ключевых слов для каждой темы. Например 1 тема: [ ядерный - 0.63, оружие - 0.55, терроризм - 0.49, угроза - 0.32],
2 тема: [интеграция - 0.63, санкции - 0.55, блокада -0.25, спад - 0.11 ],  3 тема: [экономика - 0.63, торговдя - 0.55, сотрудничество - 0.25, развитие. - 0.11 ]. Вот такого плана, для каждой темы есть список ключевых слов с весом каждого слова для данной темы. На вход поступает текст и программа обработав его пословно определяет какой доли слов больше и соотносит к теме. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с таким или знает как делать, с помощью какой библиотеки это можно решить

Comment: Такс, объясните, пожалуйста, конкретнее. Эти цифры - процент этого слова в тексте от общего кол-ва слов или что-то другое? Если другое, то что именно?

Comment: Скорее коэффициент этого слова для данной категории темы. Я их сам задаю То есть если встречается в тексте слово ядерный и спад. Вероятность у ядерного в теме 1 -0.63. а у спада 0.11 во 2 теме. значит текст скорее всего относится к теме 1. но возможно классификацию можно реализовать по другому методу